# Use of に with 先週

Tags: grammar, particle-に, time

I saw this sentence on a Japanese teaching site:

> 事故は先週に起こった
> The incident occurred last week

I feel very uncomfortable with the に on 先週.
[This post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/84536/difference-between-%E6%AF%8E%E6%97%A5%E3%81%AB-and-%E6%AF%8E%E6%97%A5) and [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/68550/what-is-relative-time-in-japanese-language) seem to back up my discomfort. Is this sentence ungrammatical/unnatural or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you tell me which Japanese teaching site?

Comment: @JimmyYang It was Duolingo. It has a lot of stuff which seems unnatural to me, but it's good for improving my terrible listening skills so I keep ploughing through it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a native speaker, I also feel uncomfortable with 事故は先週に起こった, which can be said to be a little unnatural but probably cannot be said to be ungrammatical. 先週 plays the role of an adverb in this sentence, so its natural sentence will be:

- 事故は先週起こった。

But as a writer, I would like to avoid this, because I don't like the awkward sequence of Chinese characters of 先週 + 起. So I like this sentence transcribed like this with the use of punctuation marks.

- 事故は(、)先週、起こった。
- 先週、事故は起こった。(very natural to me)

This point might be trivial for other Japanese, but I am always wondering how to use this kind of noun phrase used as an adverb. In order to avoid this (discomfort), I prefer the following to the above sentence.

- 事故は先週のあいだに起こった。(a little longer, but very natural to me)

After answering this question, I hit upon the following sentence.

- 先週**に**起こった事故は、すごかった。

This sentence with に in it is, no doubt, grammatical and quite natural. I have no idea of the cause of the difference in naturalness and grammaticality between this and the above sentence (事故は先週に起こった).

Comment: Very interesting point about consecutive kanji lining up in that way.  For me, that's perhaps the most informative aspect of this answer (and the use of commas).

Answer (score 3):

文法的には間違ってはないと思います。
使い方によっては不自然に感じられるかもしれません。
おそらく日本人が
「事故は先週に起こった」
と聞けば、「先週」という部分が強調されているように感じると思います。つまりいつ起こったのかを強調したいときには、「先週」に「に」をつけるのは自然です。
例えば誰かに
「事故はいつ起こったのか？」
と質問されて、それに答える文として
「先週に起こった」
というのならしっくりくる表現です。

先週を強調しない言い方なら
「先週、事故が起こった」
と言うと不自然には感じません。